# How to check if and image is mono color or empty?

Tags: php, image, gd

I need to prevent users from uploading blank profile images. For blank images I mean a full white or any other full color image.
I think the best approach is to check if the images contains just one color but i don't know how to do it.

I'm trying to check this after the image is uploaded, just to simplify things.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: some like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104420/image-magick-detect-colors-contained-on-a-image

Comment: @Hammurabi Thanks, but I'm using GD not Magick. I just need to know if all pixels are the same color. Some people suggest to resize image to a few pixels and then check pixel by pixel. I don't know if this is the best method but i don't know how to make it work anyways. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check whole image

1) Resize your image to smaller one (eg resize it originalSize/10 or sth like this...)
2) Use [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get image size
3) Loop throught pixels, save the color of first one and continue till the color of pixels on position x,y is different or until there are no more pixels unchecked.

```
    <?php

function isColorSame($imgname){
$img = imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imgname);

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

$starterColor = imagecolorat(0, 0, $img);

while($x < $width){
    while($y < $height) {
        if (imagecolorat($x, $y, $img) !== $starterColor){
            return false;
        }
        $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
return true;
}
```

## Guess

Check just few pixels (eg. 100 pixels) by generating random x,y and checking color at this position. This is not 100% sure, but after this, you can pass the image to the function, which checks all pixels.

Comment: Thanks @Eakethet, I have test your idea and it works. Anyways, as I have just tested it, this wont prevent any user from uploading an image that looks as a blank image even if it is not really. If the image is 99% same white pixels and just one pixel is a little bit different, the image will be posted because the script finds out not every pixel is the same. It is not a problem with your solution, it is a problem in the way I'm trying to prevent this. Thanks again.

Comment: @NicoSanchez Well, you can try some AI image recognition. There will be some api service i think, or you can play with tensorflow and its python libraries, if you would like to achieve your own solution.
If you wanna handle it in some simple php function, you could also try count number of different colors in image (probably there could be some easy function, or play with resizing image). You could also easily find out, if there is only straight line, or if it is more complicated shape. But I would still recommend some manual validation of those rejected profiles.